# How can I get text out of a <dt> tag with a <span> inside?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text from inside a `<dt>` tag with a `<span>` inside on www.uszip.com:

Here is an example of what I'm trying to get:

```
<dt>Land area<br><span class="stype">(sq. miles)</span></dt>
<dd>14.28</dd>
```

I want to get the `14.28` out of the tag. This is how I'm currently approaching it:

Note: soup is the BeautifulSoup version of the entire webpage's source code:

```
soup.find("dt",text="Land area").contents[0]
```

However, this is giving me a

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents'
```

I've tried a lot of things and I'm not sure how to approach this. This method works for some of the other data on this page, like:

```
<dt>Total population</dt>
<dd>22,234<span class="trend trend-down" title="-15,025 (-69.77% since 2000)">&#9660;</span></dd>
```

Using `soup.find("dt",text="Total population").next_sibling.contents[0]` on this returns `'22,234'`.

How should I try to first identify the correct tag and then get the right data out of it?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot match tags with both text and nested tags, based on the contained text alone.

You'd have to loop over all `<dt>` *without* text:

```
for dt in soup.find_all('dt', text=False):
    if 'Land area' in dt.text:
        print dt.contents[0]
```

This sounds counter-intuitive, but the `.string` attribute for such tags is empty, and that is what BeautifulSoup is matching against. `.text` contains all strings in all nested tags combined, and that is not matched against.

You could also use a [custom function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to do the search:

```
soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'dt' and 'Land area' in t.text)
```

which essentially does the same search with the filter encapsulated in a `lambda` function.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but it gave me the same error message again. I don't know if it's finding the correct tag.

Comment: Then you are looking at a page with no `<dt>` tag with the string `Land area` directly contained. Do you have a link?

Comment: For example: www.uszip.com/zip/48167
I used this to get soup:

` url = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 content = url.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(content)`

Comment: No, indeed, I see the tag you want but the text matching misses it. Probably because there are other nested tags. You'll have to loop, I'll update.

Comment: You can also try matching against 'Land area(sq. miles)', if you print the text of the dt tag that is what you get and might be why just 'Land area' wasn't working.

Comment: @dan: No, you are looking at the `.text` property, not `.string`. I address this in my answer, specifically. And a regular expression would match a substring, so should match `Land area` still.