# BeautifulSoup4 i tag within a tag breaks search by text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Expected:

```
>>> s = BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://example.com">lele</a>')
>>> s.find('a', text='lele')
<a href="http://lele.com">lele</a>
```

Unexpected:

```
>>> s = BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://example.com">lele<i><i></a>')
>>> s.find('a', text='lele')              # return None
>>> s.find('a', text=re.compile('lele'))  # return None
```

So in the unexpected case, an i tag inside an a tag seems to break the searching function by text, even with regex. Is there a way to make search by text work in the unexpected case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get text out of a <dt> tag with a <span> inside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725787/how-can-i-get-text-out-of-a-dt-tag-with-a-span-inside)

Comment: Sorry, the broken-html thing was a red herring; the problem is with the combination of text and a nested tag. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: The solution is to use `s.find('a', text=False)` and test for `lele in result.text`.