# Beautiful Soup, searching by content of tag with tag in it

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

```
<th rowspan="3" style="background:#c0cfe4; width:7em">present</th>
<td>ich <a href="/wiki/mache" title="mache">mache</a></td>
<td>wir <strong class="selflink">machen</strong></td>
<th rowspan="3" style="background:#c0cfe4; width:7em">i</th>
<td>ich <a href="/wiki/mache" title="mache">mache</a></td>
<td>wir <strong class="selflink">machen</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>du <a href="/wiki/machst" title="machst">machst</a></td>
<td>ihr <a href="/wiki/macht" title="macht">macht</a></td>
<td>du <a href="/wiki/machest" title="machest">machest</a></td>
<td>ihr <a href="/wiki/machet" title="machet">machet</a></td>
</tr>
<th colspan="6" style="background:#9999DF">future i</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th rowspan="3" style="background:#ccccff">infinitive</th>
<td rowspan="3" colspan="2">machen werden</td>
<th rowspan="3" style="background:#ccccff">subjunctive i</th>
<td>ich werde machen</td>
<td>wir werden machen</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>du werdest machen</td>
<td>ihr werdet machen</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>er werde machen</td>
<td>sie werden machen</td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to extract `<td>du <a href="/wiki/machst" title="machst">machst</a></td>` on line 9. When I perform a search using `soup.find_all("td" text="re.compile("^du))` all I get is the  tag on line 24. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this effects the problem, but I noticed that your first `</tr>` end tag on line 7 is missing a corresponding `<tr>` start tag.  I assume that you just missed copying the tag when you created the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach, you get the [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) `td` that has a [`text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) starting with `du`:

```
print next(td for td in soup.find_all("td") if td.text.startswith('du'))
```

Also, you can [pass a function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
def td_with_du(tag):
    return tag.name == 'td' and tag.text.startswith('du')

print soup.find_all(td_with_du)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
Your HTML code goes here
"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> def td_with_du(tag):
...     return tag.name == 'td' and tag.text.startswith('du')
... 
>>> for td in soup.find_all(td_with_du):
...     print td.text
... 
du machst
du machest
du werdest machen
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot match tags with both text and nested tags (see [How can I get text out of a <dt> tag with a <span> inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725787/how-can-i-get-text-out-of-a-dt-tag-with-a-span-inside)), which is why your only match is `<td>du werdest machen</td>`.

It turns out the `string` attribute of a Tag object is `None` when the tag itself contains nested tags. However, as Martijn Pieters states in the link above, `.text` *contains all strings in all nested tags combined*, which is why

```
>>> a = soup.find_all('td')[0]
>>> a
<td>ich <a href="/wiki/mache" title="mache">mache</a></td>
>>> print(a.string)
None
>>> print(a.text)
ich mache
>>> b = soup.find_all('td', text=re.compile('^du'))[0]
>>> b
<td>du werdest machen</td>
>>> print(b.string)
du werdest machen
>>> print(b.text)
du werdest machen
```

For the approach to solve this, you can see alecxe's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes that you are not limited to filtering on`text="re.compile("^du)`.

While there are several lines with text that begins with "du", there is only one line in your data that contains `href="/wiki/machst"`.  So, if you filter on the `href` attribute, you will get the "a" tag, and if  you take the parent of that, you will get the "td" tag that you're after:

```
soup.find(href="/wiki/machst").parent
```

If you need to use `find_all`, rather than `find`:

```
for a in soup.find_all(href="/wiki/machst"):
    print a.parent
```

If this solution can't be used for some reason, it would be helpful if you could clarify the requirements and restrictions you're operating under.