# BeautifulSoup fails at finding element using regex because of extra <br>

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup fails at finding the element with `<br>` embedded:

```
# With <br>
soup = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><strong><br>HELLO WORLD!</strong></body></html>")

# Returns None
soup.find('strong', text=re.compile(r'HELLO WORLD', re.IGNORECASE))

# Without <br>
soup2 = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><strong>HELLO WORLD!</strong></body></html>")

# Works fine!
soup.find('strong', text=re.compile(r'HELLO WORLD', re.IGNORECASE))

# <strong>HELLO WORLD!</strong>
```

I know I can get the element some other way, but this is most convenient.

Why does this not work when `<br>` is involved?

Comment: @martijnpieters Hi, I do not think this is a duplicate question. The answer in the thread you linked deals with getting the text from an element. I'm interested in getting the element based on a text string. I've edited my title to be more clear.

Comment: Right, but the *reason* for this is the same. I'll find you another post that deals with searching.

Comment: See [How can I get text out of a  tag with a  inside?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20725787) for a work-around: use a function to search for the element. I should probably have duped your post to that one instead.

Comment: I asked Jon to re-dupe this for us. Thanks @Jon!

Comment: Thanks, the thread helped.